# Apache does not start - httpd.conf in windows

Tags: apache

I am trying to set up Apache http 2.2, with mod_jk module.

The intention is to set up a load balancer right on my PC, for test purposes.

So I made some changes to httpd.conf to set some parameters, then I run it and I get the popup:
"Windows couldn't start Apache 2.2 on local PC. For more information check system events log. If it's not a windows service contact service provider and reference the code:1"

I check on the log and I get:

httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.0.35 for ServerName

So I uncomment on httpd.conf line: ServerName myPcName:80 and run it again.
I get the same popup, but this time I don't get anything on the events log.

Any idea on how to let it work?

(Nothing is bound on 80 port.)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if port 80 is being used by other application or not. Most of the time in my case "Skype" was using port 80. So I had to stop it and then I used to start Apache service.

To troubleshoot further what you can do is, goto apache's bin directory and run httpd.exe -t option. This will show you exactly what is causing problem.

Comment: Thank you Alpesh, I run httpd.exe -t and it worked well, so I don't know why the service is not started.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file in the apache /conf folder, has a piece of code that starts from `C:`.  It is copyrighted and therefore you cannot change the code.

All you have to do is make a second copy of the whole apache folder and put it directly in your `C:` directory.  Your apache file is in `System 32` causing you to use cprompt right. Having 2 identical apache folders one in `C:` and one in `System 32`  bypasses the problem.